# nvarchar or varchar or date in joins of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce-4

I have a management project developed in Web using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Windows Application using SQL Server CE 4.0.

Both uses almost same database structure. I have a fees table as :

```
TABLE [fees] 
(
    [feeid] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [acno] int NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [billingmonth] nvarchar(10) NULL,
    [oldbal] numeric(18,2) NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [duedtamt] numeric(18,2) NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [afterdtamt] numeric(18,2) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [bal] numeric(18,2) NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [depamt] numeric(18,2) NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [totdpo] numeric(18,2) NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [depdt] datetime NULL
)
```

`billingmonth` will always use format `MMM-yyyy` eg. Jan-2018

`BillingMonth` uses various joins (inner and left outer join) in other tables.

How to increase performance of joins with `BillingMonth` ? , should i :

- Convert nvarchar to varchar ( as it will always store Month in SQL2008R2 )
- Convert nvarchar to datetime ( as first day of month 01-MMM-yyyy in SQL Server CE and SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Big **NO** to `varchar/nvarchar`. Date should be stored in `Date` datatype period. Store it in date datatype and create an index to increase the performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Storing date values as nvarchar is not recommended at all**

There are many suggestions to increase the join performance:

- Use `Date` datatype
- Use two numeric field month and year instead of one varchar field *(`tinyint` for month, `smallint` for year, they can be used **only for joining purpose**)*

*Note that: AS @Pரதீப் mentioned, When you store month and year separately, you need to do some integer manipulations when searching for date ranges*

Comment: I wouldn't recommend your second suggestion. When you store month and year separately, you need to do some integer manipulations when searching for date ranges. Better to store date in Date type

Comment: I also agree with that.  Imagine trying to do `>= '2017-04-01' AND < '2018-04-01'` *(to get a financial year)* if the year and month are stored separately.  Store dates as `DATE`s, else what's the point in that data-type??

Comment: Maybe it is better to add these columns for JOIN operations only? because from performance perspective using smallint and tinyint is more efficient than date. maybe it is better to combine both suggestions?

Comment: i think that as example `[MonthCol1]  = [Monthcol2] is better than MONTH([DateCol1]) = MONTH([Datecol2])`

Comment: SQLCE uses datetime. as per requirement, this field usage is ONLY for month and year i.e. billingMonth with year (MMM-yyyy).. Should i use datetime to increase performance ? It is  using in many inner and outer joins like... Select * from  fees inner join on revenue on fees.billingmonth=revenue.billingmonth ...

Comment: @Admin yes datetime will increase performance more than varchar or nvarchar

Comment: @Admin also i suggested adding two other fields only for joining purpose, and the remarks given as comments to my answer should be considered.

Comment: @MatBailie these aren't dates. Dates represent a single day. Not a whole month.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I disagree with that.  A date data-point represents a single point in time; midnight at the start of that day.  Be that represented with a `DATETIME` or even a `DATE` data-type, I would still argue the same.  The only difference being the granularity of the measurement along the time dimension.  Convention and context then dictate the interpretation of what that point in time means.  It may mean exactly a point in time, the whole day from the point forward, or the start of a month from that point forward.  But I do not agree that it *intrinsically* means a whole day.